# ProxyPass not setting port

Tags: apache2, jetty

I'm trying to run a jetty/wicket application behind a proxy. This to avoid users to type the port number of the jetty.

```
 ProxyPass        /test http://xx.xx.xx.xxx:8012/myapp
 ProxyPassReverse /test http://xx.xx.xx.xxx:8012/myapp
 ProxyPassReverseCookiePath / /test
```

When I'm trying to connect to xx.xx.xx.xxx/test it redirects to

```
http://xx.xx.xx.xxx/myapp
```

This gives me an error message since it's trying to connect on port 80?
How should I write this proxy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy solution is to match exactly the same path. Something like this:

```
ProxyPass                    /myapp    http://localhost:8012/myapp
ProxyPassReverse             /myapp    http://localhost:8012/myapp  
ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain localhost www.publicdomain.net
```

Comment: Alright I have failled again. I had http://localhost:8012/myapp/ so that resulted in a // . I saw it when I check the logs. Thanks anyway.